# How to specify a generic path?

Tags: c#, .net, path

I would like to know if it is possible to specify a generic path when writing to disk?

Say i have this path: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET`

How would i make the path generic when writing to that destination?

Not all local paths are set to `c:\`.

I did try: `..\Program Files\Microsoft.NET` but with no luck

**UPDATE:**

I need to write to a specific location/Path, but the path changes all the time... It will not always be to `Program Files\Microsoft.NET`. The next time around that i need to write to disk is might be a complete new destination Path, like: `c:\NewTestFolder\Test1`
That is why i need a "Generic" way of specifying the `c:\` part of the path.

Comment: what do you need to do exactly? do you have to read or write to a specific location or what else?

Comment: What do you mean by "generic"?

Comment: What do you mean with "generic path"? If you want the root directory from the disk where is your application it's similiar to linux: `\Program Files\Microsoft.NET` - but using an environment variable would be much better.

Comment: YOu mean the programs folder (which is a special known folder andere there is an enumeration) or something more generic (which is not possible).

Comment: @Jon Skeet : Please have a look at my update.

Comment: Once again - what means "generic"? Where do you get the "C:" (or what else) from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string tempPath = "..\\Program Files\\Microsoft.NET";
string outputPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(tempPath);
```

The result will be `C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft.NET`

Comment: But that will generating a path relative to the parent folder of the current folder the program is running in!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Environment class.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
```

With that call you get the path to the program files directory.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Environment class, but note that if you use the version of Windows after Windows XP, you can not write or read in the specified path, and unless you have administrator privileges.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variables. %ProgramFiles% results in your example in C:\Program Files

To use environment variables you can use the Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables method:

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%");
```